# Access form doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

i am using Access 2010 and i wanted to make a form for restaurant check, If you write into the text field the name: Mayer then you have to get a message in the label and if you write Schmidt it should return another message and so on.. I have to do it using Select case (for Class homework) here is my code because it doesn't work, i click the check button and nothing happens.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Sub btnCheck_Click()
Dim txtEingabe As String
Dim Mayer As String
Dim Schmidt As String

Select Case txtEingabe
    Case Mayer
    lblAusgabe = "Reserviert"
Case Schmidt
    lblAusgabe = "Nicht Reserviert"
Case Else
    lblAusgabe = "Falsche Name"
End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this instead. You don't need variables here for what you're trying to do.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnCheck_Click()

    Select Case Nz(Me.txtEingabe.Value, "") 'Should be the name of your textbox
        Case "Mayer"
            lblAusgabe.Caption = "Reserviert"
        Case "Schmidt"
            lblAusgabe.Caption = "Nicht Reserviert"
        Case Else
            lblAusgabe.Caption = "Falsche Name"
    End Select

End Sub
```

If you want to use an input box that pops up and ask for input, then you'll need to use a variable and the InputBox function.

Comment: Your solution works pretty good, thanks! I found out why it wasn't working with this. I haven't clicked the activate button on top to activate extra functions.